# Binding youtube link in Angular 8?

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4

I have problem with video, link is in array and binding doesnt work

```
<div class="card mb-4" *ngFor="let clip of clips">
              <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" [src]="clip.src"></iframe>
                </div>
              <div class="card-body">
              <h2 class="card-title">{{clip.src}}</h2>
              <p class="card-text">{{clip.description}}</p>
            </div>
```

if i binding link like 'http://' it is ok. If binding like `[src]="clip.src" or src="{{clip.src}}"` doesnt work. How i can use src from object to binding?

Comment: what is the value of `clip.src`?

Comment: you see a security related error in the console?

Comment: clip.src it is youtube link

Comment: Angular Components is adding a Youtube component in version 9, it is still not published at this time but maybe you can try it out https://github.com/angular/components/blob/9.0.x/src/youtube-player/youtube-player.ts

Answer (score 0):

What you have looks like it should work.  You might need to create a safeUrl pipe to bypass the DOM Sanitizer.

This is a good article on that.

https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/angular-safe-pipe-implementation-to-bypass-domsanitizer-stripping-out-content-c1bf0f1cc36b

In short, Angular is trying to protect your users from XSS.  You know the link is safe, but Angular does not so it is stripping it out of the markup to protect users.  Bypassing the DOM Sanitizer stops Angular from doing such.

Comment: If my comment answered your question, please mark it as correct.